# Create Metaboxes dynamically in admin for Pages

Tags: php, javascript, metabox

I've created in the admin editor of my site homepage a Metabox with an `input` and a `textarea` fields. The code works great. However my goal is to allow the admin user to duplicate the Metabox with the same fields (of course no value inside) by clicking on a button "Add new".

The concept: the user can add as many sections as he wants in the front end of the site homepage. A section corresponds to a Metabox (title + description).

Here is the code of my Metabox:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'mysite_home_add_meta_box' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'mysite_home_add_meta_box' ) ) {
    function mysite_home_add_meta_box() {
        add_meta_box( 'additional-page-metabox-options', esc_html__( 'Section 1', 'mysite' ), 'mysite_home_metabox_controls', 'page', 'normal', 'low' );
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'mysite_home_metabox_controls' ) ) {
    function mysite_home_metabox_controls( $post ) {
        $meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );
        $section_title_home_input_field = ( isset( $meta['section_title_home_input_field'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['section_title_home_input_field'][0] ) ? $meta['section_title_home_input_field'][0] : '';
        $section_descr_home_textarea_field = ( isset( $meta['section_descr_home_textarea_field'][0] ) && '' !== $meta['section_descr_home_textarea_field'][0] ) ? $meta['section_descr_home_textarea_field'][0] : '';
        wp_nonce_field( 'mysite_home_control_meta_box', 'mysite_home_control_meta_box_nonce' );
        ?>
        <div class="post_meta_extras">
            <p>
                <label><?php esc_attr_e( 'Title', 'mysite' ); ?></label>
                <input type="text" name="section_title_home_input_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $section_title_home_input_field ); ?>">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label><?php esc_attr_e( 'Description', 'mysite' ); ?></label>
                <textarea type="text" name="section_descr_home_textarea_field" id="" class="widefat" cols="100%" rows="8"><?php echo esc_attr( $section_descr_home_textarea_field ); ?></textarea>
            </p>
        <?php
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'mysite_home_save_metaboxes' );
if ( ! function_exists( 'mysite_home_save_metaboxes' ) ) {
    function mysite_home_1_save_metaboxes( $post_id ) {

        if ( ! isset( $_POST['mysite_home_control_meta_box_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['mysite_home_control_meta_box_nonce'] ), 'mysite_home_control_meta_box' ) ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' === $_POST['post_type'] ) {
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        } else {
            if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
                return $post_id;
            }
        }

        if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
            return $post_id;
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['section_title_home_input_field'] ) ) { 
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'section_title_home_input_field', sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['section_title_home_input_field'] ) ) );
        }

        if ( isset( $_POST['section_descr_home_textarea_field'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'section_descr_home_textarea_field', $_POST['section_descr_home_textarea_field'] );
        }

    }
}
```

I'm struggling to find a solution. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm trying your code but _The code works great._ does not apply to me.. You mention adding metaboxes to the  _admin of my homepage_ but it's not clear to me if you talk about the admin dashboard or (?)

Comment: Hi, sorry I just updated the code and removed the conditional `if($pageTemplate == 'page-home.php')`. The Metabox is in the admin editor for Pages.

Comment: I suggest you use custom library called CMB2 to add custom meta boxes. It makes process of adding metaboxes very easy and have a concept called repeater, so if you set that parameter to true , you allow users to add a custom field or group of fields by clicking add more button.

Comment: https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Basic-Usage#getting-started see parameter called 'repeater'

Comment: Thanks Mohsin. I would prefer not to use any plugin but CMB2 looks great. I will look into it.